# The local computer does not support the required data encryption type

Tags: c#, encryption

I am trying to setup vpn connection via c# code. all works fine, but after connection I have got the "The local computer does not
support the required data
encryption type." exception. How could I change this type? Or completely disable the encryption?
my code is:

```
RasEntry.CreateVpnEntry(connectionName, serverAddress, RasVpnStrategy.Default, RasDevice.GetDeviceByName("(PPTP)", RasDeviceType.Vpn), false);
```

...

```
this.dialer.EntryName = entry.Name;
                this.dialer.PhoneBookPath = entry.Owner.Path;    
    this.dialer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "passw");
                this.dialer.SynchronizingObject = new DispatcherSynchronizingObject(App.Current.Dispatcher);
                this.dialer.EapOptions = new DotRas.RasEapOptions(false, false, false);
                this.dialer.HangUpPollingInterval = 0;
                this.dialer.Options = new DotRas.RasDialOptions(false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false);
                this.dialer.DialAsync();
```

Ihave add

```
entry.EncryptionType = RasEncryptionType.None;
```

but this result in Error 734: The PPP Link Control Protocol Was Terminated
Ihave read this article (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ebe6dc34-873f-41e6-8b71-8b0cf3930b35/error-734-the-ppp-link-control-protocol-was-terminated?forum=itprovistanetworking) and make all that described in it but the error still here.

Comment: have you tried looking here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929856

Comment: Yes, I have seen that. I think I need to setup this in my code somehow.

Comment: Try RasEncryptionType.RequireMax or RasEncryptionType.Require.

Comment: I have try all of this - still same error

Comment: Hello i have same problem and the problem is resolved but setting 
                entry.EncryptionType = RasEncryptionType.Optional;